# Best way to store high res image drawable

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable

I have an app that has 5 high resolution images in `.jpg` format. The images only served as a background of the layout but the problem is i am storing all of it inside `drawable-xxxhdpi` because if i store it in the `drawable` it lags the device. I know that i'm not doing it very efficiently i'm not a good UI designer i just want to have the high res image as the layout's background.

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Read the documentation about supporting different layout sizes: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Comment: @Prexx Thanks, I know Android Asset Studio is only for icons i tried it but obviously it ruins the quality of the image. Is there the same tool but for generic images?

Comment: Just store your images in the xxhdpi, xhdpi, ... folders. The scale factors are in the link i posted. You can downsize them in Paint or whatever and put them in the folders

Comment: Why not upload the images somewhere and use Glide to fetch them at runtime?.

Comment: @MbuodileObiosio Thank you, My app's functionality is only for offline use and i am using Glide for loading images locally from Uri. But the apps high res background layout is already set explicitly in the xml so no need to use glide in that case.